# How to store stored procedure results to a variable in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do I store the results from my stored procedure to variables? Here is my sample code:

```
public ActionResult ManageProfile(string eid)
{
     var vm = new ManageProfileViewModel();   // Call ViewModel
     sp_GetUserDetails_Result gResult = db_RIRO.sp_GetUserDetails(Session["EID"].ToString()).First();
     // Get UserId, FirstName, LastName from stored procedure result
     gResult.UserId = vm.UserId;
     gResult.FirstName = vm.FirstName;
     gResult.LastName = vm.LastName;

    return View(vm);
}
```

The stored procedure works fine when I manually try to execute it in Management Studio. The problem with my code is after executing it returns a `null`.

Comment: Could you show `sp_GetUserDetails` method and store procedure itself?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2):

Assigning of my variables should be the other way around.

`vm.FirstName = gResult.SAPID`

instead of

`gResult.SAPID = vm.FirstName`.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell you without seeing the stored procedure.
Make sure your stored procedure has output parameter.

For example, if you have a output variable "@userId" from stored procedure:
something like in your code:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@userId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = "";
sqlcmd.Parameters["@userId"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;using
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConnStr))
{
   sqlcmd.Connection = conn;
   conn.Open();
   sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
   if(sqlcmd.Parameters["@userId"].SqlValue.ToString() != "Null")
   {
      gResult.UserId = sqlcmd.Parameters["@userId"].SqlValue.ToString();
   }
}
```

Hope this pseudo code helps you.